# Dagger-like weapon used by Kaecillius

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

In movie Doctor strange, on a number of occasions, *Kaecilius* brings out a dagger which somewhat looks like made from dark matter.

What is this weapon called and what is it made of?.

It even appears in the second official trailer of *Avengers:Infinity War*, which showing dozens of similar weapons pointing at Stephen Strange.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't seem to have official names, and are just referred to as "space shards". From [this analysis](https://www.framestore.com/doctorstrange):

> As well as key sequences and effects, Framestore also worked on the Crimson Bands of Cyttorak, a harness used by Strange to restrain Kaecilius; the **Space Shard** effect used by the Zealots; and the Space Portal.

We currently don't know if the weapons shown in the second Infinity War trailer are the same thing, as Ebony Maw (the character shown next to Dr. Strange) doesn't practice magic.

Comment: A wikia is not really authoritative since it's fan created nor is there a source for the description they provide.

Comment: I edited the answer to follow a source cited by the wikia, which was the only other answer I could fine

Comment: Ebony Maw doesn't practice magic directly, but, he does have the power of mind control, and it's possible that he could persuade Dr. Strange to torture himself.